# Custom Routing in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, routes

I am using mvc4 framework and .net framwork 4.5. I need a url like this:

`www.examples.com/name` (*note:  'name' will be change dynamically*)

which routes to the same page.

I have tried like this but getting error

My action method is like this:

```
public ActionResult Userlist(string status)
{
    return View();
}
```

Route Config

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 "user",
                "{status}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Userlist" }
            );
```

How can I create a route syntax and redirect this to a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Add this route config
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default_Userlist",
        url: "{status}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Userlist" },
        namespaces: new[] { "MyMvcProject.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "MyMvcProject.Controllers" }
    );

}
```

Don't forget to replace the "MyMvcProject" with the name of your project.

**Issue**

This is a bad practice because the value of the status could easily cause conflicts with your action methods.

Comment: I have tried this code i got same error. It will working following url format http://localhost:19615/home/UserList/sajith, but i need to http://localhost:19615/sajith

Comment: Have you replaced MyMvcProject with the name of your project? also, you need to place this code before the default route (see my updated answer)

Comment: This is working..!!!!!!!!!! LOL...!!  Thanks.. lot you have save my valuable time.